# setcookie() always removes cookie (or don't remove because it was never set)

Tags: php, http, cookies

Server sends Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT even if I set `expires` to 2147483647:

```php
if(!setcookie("auth-data", $data, [
      'expires' => 2147483647,
      'samesite' => 'Lax',
      'path' => '...'
]))
{
  http_response_code(405);
  echo "{\"status\":\"failed to set cookie\"}";
  exit;
}
```

Not worked: setting `expires` to `0`, `-1`, `time() + 60*60*24*40`, `time() + another value`, ...

Server response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 24 Oct 2020 10:38:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie: auth-data=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=...; SameSite=Lax
...
```

Comment: This could be a problem of the timezone config. Did you try something like `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`?

Comment: Please check the manual. I think you are calling `setcookie` with a wrong number and type of arguments.